# How to run shell scripts cross-platform, using npm

Tags: npm, cross-platform, nestjs

I have nestJS project with that line in package.json:

```
 "scripts": {
...
"test": "sh scripts/test.sh",
...
  },
```

And on my windows machine, it can't run.

How to rewrite it, to run cross-platform? May be example using cross-env-shell or add some package in dependencies?

Comment: it can run in windows if you use the right shell, I guess.

Comment: @MicaelLevi I know that. Need to set "Shell path" in terminal settings. But I think that there is some universal way.

Comment: I've searched for this in the past but didn't find any universal way that don't use nodejs itself to choose the right `test.sh` script, like `"test": "node run.js"`

Comment: Take a look at [run-script-os](https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-script-os)